# Start new Transaction in the middle of rollback

Tags: java, transactions, jboss, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am using Jboss5.1.x EJB3.0

I am trying to open new Transaction in the middle of rollback in order to write into database.

the only way I could do i
t, is when I wrap the transaction in a seperate thread, which seems not right to me. 
It could cause any problems? and what is the sense of doing it(wrap with new Thread), 
it suppose to work without it isn't it?

code:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void updateCurrentRetryInDB(final CounterCallData counterCall)
{
    Thread t = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                ECMSDao.insertErrorToLog(counterCall.getModemIp(), "Time out");
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("SQL Exception:" + e.getMessage());
                logger.error(TAG + ".updateCurrentRetryInDB, SQLException Error", e);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same requirements as you, writing something in the database in the middle of a rollback.

What I did is create a new stateful EJB that has `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` and calling a save method that stores in the database.

I didn't create a new thread or anything, because this is supposed to be handled by the container.

So in your case, I guess the `ECMSDao` should be a `@Stateful` ejb with  `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` and not the method `updateCurrentRetryInDB()`

**Update**

Say you have a normal situation where are storing something, and a rollback occurs.
In this example, I am simulating with a managed transaction.

```
public class Foo {

@PersistenceContext EntityManager em;

@Inject BarImpl bar; //can also use @EJB depending on your environment

public void fail() {
   try {
     //do some thing and throw exception to simulate rollback
      throw new RuntimeException("Exception occured, please rollback");
   } catch(Exception ex) {
     bar.save(ex.getMessage()); // <-- This will store the exception message in a new transaction whilst the other transaction is safely rolledback
     throw ex;
   }
}

@Scope(SESSION)
@Stateful
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER) //default
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class BarImpl implements Bar {

   @PersistenceContext EntityManager em;    
   @Destroy @Remove public void destroy(){}

    public void save(String msg) { 
      MyEntity m = new MyEntity(); 
      m.setMessage(msg); 
      em.persist(m);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that ECMSDao is not an EJB, it's just a pojo.. i am not using JPA, i am using regular jdbc.. any idea how could I solve this?

Comment: I think you are confused of the different terms here. The question was tagged ejb, and you are using @TransactionAttribute which is an ejb specific annotation. You cannot use that in conjuction with normal pojo. Using JPA has nothing to do with it. You can use JPA, no problem. I can give a short demonstration

Comment: @Shervin Have you tested if this works? When I was testing something similar I found that REQUIRES_NEW only means that a rollback in the new transaction wont affect the old one but that if the old transaction is rolled back all changes are rolled back.

Comment: Yes I have tested it and it works. We are using it in production where we are storing all exceptions that occurs in the database, and this is how we are doing it

Comment: Nice, I'll have too look into this again.

Comment: @Shervim it ,ust be annotated as @statefull ?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to say, that it worked also with annotation of the specific method also, you need to annotate the whole class

Comment: @rayman: I am not sure if it has to be Stateful. Try Stateless and see if it works

Answer (score -1):

there is no such thing as "middle of rollback", since transaction is atomic, thus it either has been rolled back or has not. I'd suggest jms for logging. 
Also note that according to JSR 220: Enterprise JavaBeansTM,Version 3.0:

"The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise bean must not attempt
to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or to chang", so at least you may affect portability.

Comment: This is not correct. You can start a new transaction and store that in a middle of a rollback as my example illustrates

Comment: when you start new transaction, the old one is not in a rollback since you catched exception. It's just postponed, from 13.6.2.4 REQUIRES_NEW:  "If a client calls with a transaction context, the container suspends the association of the transaction context
with the current thread before starting the new transaction and invoking the business method. The
container resumes the suspended transaction association after the business method and the new transaction
have been completed."

Comment: I'd be more concirned with statefull bean, btw, why should it be statefull, does it behaviour differe from stateless? I know jboss claims that SFSB are as fast as stateless, but if only this app happen to be deployed to WS i'm afraid there will be problems with performance.